# Metric for vector sets

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, vector-analysis

I am currently working on a classification algorithm. Each class is represented by a set of 3D vectors. The cardinality differs for each class. The order of the vectors in a set is completly random.

To assign a new measurement (again represented by a set for 3D vectors) I have to find the class with the minimum distance. However, i am not able to define a metric to measure the distances between the sets.

Any advise or hint for further research is welcome!

**EDIT:** Imagine the follwing example: class A is represented by a set with cardinality 10, class B is represented by a set with cardinality 5. My observation is represented by a set with 7 3D vectors. How can I calculate the distance between my observation and the two classes?

Comment: Velcome to our site!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks!

Comment: Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are doing clustering? I am not sure what you mean by distance (you first say that a class has a distance, and then you say you want to "measure the distances between the sets"), but if you are referring to distances between points, then see [this](http://zdb.ru.lv/conferences/3/VTR8_II_70.pdf). Reading up on other introductions to clustering would probably be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!. Indeed i am doing clustering. I know how to calculate the distances between single vectors, but not how to calculate them between sets of vectors. See my edit for an example.

Comment: @Ennosigaeon One naive way is to compare the cluster centers (the "average" of each set).

Comment: I will give it a try, but I don't think that it will work. The vector space is quite small and probably the cluster centers will quite near to each other.